# I there a way to combine more than one Active Record relation into a single query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a group class like this. Groups have many people.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  def notices
    Notice.where(:person_id => people).where("radius <= ?", radius)
  end
end
```

In my notices controller, I want to show all notices from all the users groups, without duplication.
Currently I'm doing this, which is lame. Is there a way to combine the queries from each group to return a relation, rather than an Array?

```
class NoticesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @groups = current_person.groups
    @notices = []
    @groups.each do |g|
      @notices += g.notices
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: can you give a more concrete example?  are you talking about chaining active record queries conditionally?

Comment: Let me edit the question to be more concrete

Answer (score 2):

I am Assuming There is A Person Model.

Okay.

Try This.

In Person model, Add this

```
has_many :all_group_members, through: :groups, class_name: "Person"
```

then add this method

```
def all_notices
  Notice.where(:person_id => all_group_members.pluck(:id)).where("radius <= ?", radius)
end
```

Finally in your controller u can do this

```
current_person.all_notices
```